# Android Development make Buttons work like RadioButtons

Tags: android

I have 11 Buttons with Background Images and if i switch to the actual RadioButton the circle thing on the RadioButton would show up and make my Background drawables ugly is there a way to make buttons work like RadioButtons?

Comment: Why don't you customise the style of the RadioButton widget to not have the circles?

Comment: What is happening when you click one of the buttons? Does the image change?

Comment: Is it possible to remove the circles on the RadioButtton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the image changes when you click on the button to show it is selected.  In that case, in your onclicklistener for the first button, you could change the image of that button to show it is selected, and also change the images of the other buttons to the unselected image.  Do the same for each button.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks

Comment: If this worked for you and you decided to use this solution can you please accept it as the answer? Thank you!